# Convert RGB Image to CMY

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How to Convert RGB color Image or simply image to CMY color Image and Extract Each Component cyan (C) magenta (M) and yellow (Y) ?
My approach :-

```
I=imread('Capture2.PNG'); 
I3 = I;
I2 =I;
I1 = I;

I1(:,:,2:3)=0;
RED = I1;

I2(:,:,1:2) = 0;
BLUE = I2;

I3(:,:,1:3)=0;
GREEN=I3;

tic;
figure;imshow(RED);
figure;imshow(BLUE);
figure;imshow(GREEN);
c = 1.0-RED;
m = 1.0-GREEN;
y = 1.0-BLUE;
figure;imshow(c);
figure;imshow(m);
figure;imshow(y);
```

Comment: http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&H=11#text11

Comment: Don't have matlab right now.
How is it not working?
Does `figure,imshow( cat(3,c,m,y));` work?

Comment: @haraldK Now it gives black pics

Comment: What if you try `imshow(YourImage,[])`

Comment: @illiptic No it is not working

Comment: @Benoit_11 , How to extract individual components ?

Comment: how about `imshow(uint8(c*255))`? Also btw you can do `I3(:,:,[1,3])=0;` in one line

Comment: What do you mean "how to save in matrix"?

Comment: @Dan It is showing correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`makecform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makecform.html) to create color-space transformation:

```
I=imread('Capture2.PNG');
cform = makecform('srgb2cmyk');
cmykI = applycform(I,cform);
```

---

BTW, in your question it seems like `I` is of type `uint8` and therefore in range [0..255], to get the complement of each component, you need to subtract them from 255 and not 1.0:

```
c = 255-RED;
m = 255-GREEN;
y = 255-BLUE;
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why applycform is so slow compared to say rgb2ntsc? Is there a faster way (e.g., more direct conversion that could avoid overhead etc.) ?