# Extracting CMY color components from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to extract CMY color components from an image using matlab. First I have extracted the red , blue and green components of the image , then using the following info (from the fact that RGB and CMY are complements to each other : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMY_color_model)   :

white minus red gives cyan;  white minus green gives magenta ;  white minus blue gives yellow.

The image has the type uint8 , therefore the white value is 255 . Here is the code :

```
F=imread('peppers.png');
r=F(:,:,1);
g=F(:,:,2);
b=F(:,:,3);
c=256-r;
m=256-g;
y=256-b;
CMY=cat(3,c,m,y);

CMY(:,:,1)=0;
CMY(:,:,2)=0;

imshow(CMY)
```

From the above code I am trying to visualize the yellow component but image is blue , so what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: The problem is that `imshow` interprets any 3-channel image as RGB. So by setting channels 1 and 2 to zero, the only color values you have are Blue.

Comment: please see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775172/)